# outdoor real-time zenithal people counting system

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am about to run a project of outdoor real-time zenithal people counting system.
But this kind of system will suffer several problem.

1. shadow: as it's setup at out door
2. changes of brightness
3. multiple people may recognize as a single blob.

Could somebody give me some suggestion to tackle the above mentioned problem ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV's people detector based on HOG:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html

Or OpenCV's latent svm detector with the "person" model:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html